# how to add cookies when the user login and how to delete cookies when user logout

Tags: cookies

I am already using this code add and delete in the cookies

```
deleted code:

                    String profileScore=null;
        Cookie cookiesScore =new Cookie("profileScore","");
        cookiesScore.setValue("");
        cookiesScore.setMaxAge(0);
        response.addCookie(cookiesScore);
```

but its not deleted properly please help me give any example

Answer (score 0):

**Try this if using javascript**

**create a cookie:**

```
call a this method at login:

     function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
    {
         var exdate=new Date();
         exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
         var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
         document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
    }
```

**delete a cookie:**

```
call a this method at logout:

    function deleteCookies() {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = cookies[i];
            var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
            var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
            document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
        }
    }
```